JavaScript Triangles Not Scaling Correctly
I am working on a an effect that create many point and triangulates them to create a simple background animation. However, when I try to scale them down, not all lines are scaled accordingly and are often mismatched.
Here is the code that creates everything
const numNodes = 40;

let ac = [];
let moveAC = [];


const gradient = {
    len: 6,
    gradients: [
        [225, 238, 88],
        [0, 188, 212],
        [229, 115, 115],
        [74, 20, 140],
        [129, 199, 132],
        [255, 255, 255]
    ]
}

let grad1 = Math.round(Math.random() * (gradient.len - 1));
let grad2 = Math.round(Math.random() * (gradient.len - 1));

while (grad1 == grad2) {
    grad2 = Math.round(Math.random() * (gradient.len - 1));
}

console.log(grad1, grad2);

grad1 = gradient.gradients[grad1];
grad2 = gradient.gradients[grad2];

function initialize_background() {
    for (let i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {
        let posX = Math.random() * 100;
        let posY = Math.random() * 100;
        let coord = [posX, posY]
        ac.push(coord);

        let vecX = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
        let vecY = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
        let vector = [vecX, vecY];
        moveAC.push(vector);
    }

    let edgeSmooth = 10;

    for (let i = 1; i < edgeSmooth; i++) {
        let pos = (i / edgeSmooth) * 100;
        ac.push([pos, 0]);
        ac.push([pos, 100]);
        ac.push([0, pos]);
        ac.push([100, pos]);
        moveAC.push([0, 0]);
        moveAC.push([0, 0]);
        moveAC.push([0, 0]);
        moveAC.push([0, 0]);
    }

    ac.push([0, 0]);
    ac.push([0, 100]);
    ac.push([100, 0]);
    ac.push([100, 100]);
    moveAC.push([0, 0]);
    moveAC.push([0, 0]);
    moveAC.push([0, 0]);
    moveAC.push([0, 0]);

    updateBackground();
}

function updateElementPosition(element, index) {
    let speed = 0.1;
    let newX = element[0] + moveAC[index][0]*speed;
    let newY = element[1] + moveAC[index][1]*speed;

    newX = (newX < 0)? 100 : ((newX > 100)? 0 : newX);
    newY = (newY < 0)? 100 : ((newY > 100)? 0 : newY);

    ac[index] = [newX, newY];
}

async function updateBackground() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".triangle").forEach((element) => {
        element.remove();
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < ac.length; i++) {
        updateElementPosition(ac[i], i);
    }

    let triangles = orderCoordinatesToTriangles();

    const docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

    triangles.forEach((element) => {
         let child = createTriangle(ac[element[0]], ac[element[1]], ac[element[2]], element[4]);
         if (child != null) docFrag.appendChild(child);
    });

    document.getElementById("background-container").appendChild(docFrag);

    await delay(25);
    updateBackground();
    
}

function orderCoordinatesToTriangles() {
    let triangles = [];
    for (let e1 = 0; e1 < ac.length; e1 ++) {
        for (let e2 = e1+1; e2 < ac.length; e2 ++) {
            for (let e3 = e2+1; e3 < ac.length; e3 ++) {
                let coord = sortToCounterClockwise(e1, e2, e3, ac);
                let anyPointsWithin = false;

                for (let e4 = 0; e4 < ac.length; e4 ++) {
                    if (e1 == e4 || e2 == e4 || e3 == e4) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (calculateDeterminant3x3(coord, e4)) {
                        anyPointsWithin = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!anyPointsWithin) {
                    triangles.push(coord);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return triangles;
}

function calculateDeterminant3x3(coord, e4) {
    const ax = ac[(coord[0])][0];
    const ay = ac[coord[0]][1];
    const bx = ac[coord[1]][0];
    const by = ac[coord[1]][1];
    const cx = ac[coord[2]][0];
    const cy = ac[coord[2]][1];
    const dx = ac[e4][0];
    const dy = ac[e4][1];

    const det1 = (ax-dx) * calculateDeterminant2x2((by-dy), calcDifferentDet(bx, dx, by, dy), (cy-dy), calcDifferentDet(cx, dx, cy, dy));
    const det2 = (ay-dy) * calculateDeterminant2x2((bx-dx), calcDifferentDet(bx, dx, by, dy), (cx-dx), calcDifferentDet(cx, dx, cy, dy));
    const det3 = calcDifferentDet(ax, dx, ay, dy) * calculateDeterminant2x2((bx-dx), (by-dy), (cx-dx), (cy-dy));

    const result = det1 - det2 + det3;
    return (result > 0);
}

// returns (e1 - e2)^2 + (e3 - e4)^2
function calcDifferentDet(e1, e2, e3, e4) {
    return Math.pow(e1 - e2, 2) + Math.pow(e3 - e4, 2);
}

// | e1, e2 |
// | e3, e4 |
function calculateDeterminant2x2(e1, e2, e3, e4) {
    return ((e1 * e4) - (e2*e3));
}

function sortToCounterClockwise(e1, e2, e3, ac) {
    let coord = [];
    const centerX = (ac[e1][0] + ac[e2][0] + ac[e3][0])/3;
    const centerY = (ac[e1][1] + ac[e2][1] + ac[e3][1])/3;

    let angle1 = get_angle([ac[e1][0] - centerX, ac[e1][1] - centerY]);
    let angle2 = get_angle([ac[e2][0] - centerX, ac[e2][1] - centerY]);
    let angle3 = get_angle([ac[e3][0] - centerX, ac[e3][1] - centerY]);

    if (angle1 < 90) angle1 += 360;
    if (angle2 < 90) angle2 += 360;
    if (angle3 < 90) angle3 += 360;

    if (angle1 < angle2 && angle1 < angle3) {
        coord.push(e1);
        if (angle2 < angle3) {coord.push(e2); coord.push(e3);}
        else {coord.push(e3); coord.push(e2);}
    }
    else if (angle2 < angle1 && angle2 < angle3) {
        coord.push(e2);
        if (angle1 < angle3) {coord.push(e1); coord.push(e3);}
        else {coord.push(e3); coord.push(e1);}
    }
    else {
        coord.push(e3);
        if (angle1 < angle2) {coord.push(e1); coord.push(e2);}
        else {coord.push(e2); coord.push(e1);}
    }

    coord.push(centerX);
    coord.push(centerY);

    return coord;
}

const getScale = (cX, cY, pX, pY, s) => {
    sSx = window.innerWidth;
    sSy = window.innerHeight;

    v = make_vector([pX, pY], [cX, cY]);
    u = unit_vector(v);

    return (pX + s*u[0])*sSx/100 + "px " + (pY+ s*u[1])*sSy/100 + "px";
}

function createTriangle(p1, p2, p3, centerY) {
    const newTriangle = document.createElement("div");
    newTriangle.className = "triangle";
    let cX = (p1[0] + p2[0] + p3[0]) / 3;
    let cY = ((p1[1]) + (p2[1]) + (p3[1])) / 3;
    let scale = 0.2;
    
    coord1 = getScale(cX, cY, p1[0], (p1[1]), scale);
    coord2 = getScale(cX, cY, p2[0], (p2[1]), scale);
    coord3 = getScale(cX, cY, p3[0], (p3[1]), scale);
    newTriangle.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + colourFunction(0, centerY) + ", " + colourFunction(1, centerY) + ", " + colourFunction(2, centerY) + ")";
    newTriangle.style.clipPath = "polygon(" + coord1 + ", " + coord2 + ", " + coord3 + ")";

    if (!newTriangle.style.clipPath) {
        return null;
    }

    return newTriangle;
}

function colourFunction(i, cY) {
    return (grad1[i] + ((grad2[i] - grad1[i]) * (1 - (cY / 100))));
}

And the code for the vectors is as follows
//Turn current position into a vector given a vector matrix
const get_vector = (e1, e2, a) => {
    const wa = a[e2][1] - a[e1][1];
    const wb = a[e2][0] - a[e1][0];
    return [wb, wa];
};

//make a vector given arrays
const make_vector = (e1, e2) => {
    const wa = e2[1] - e1[1];
    const wb = e2[0] - e1[0];
    return [wb, wa];
};

//Get current width of a vector
const get_width = (v) => {
    const wa = Math.pow(v[0], 2);
    const wb = Math.pow(v[1], 2);
    return Math.sqrt(wa + wb);
};


//Get current angle of a vector with the line <1, 0>
const get_angle = (v) => {
    let angle = Math.acos((v[0] / get_width(v)))*180/Math.PI;
    if (v[1] < 0) {angle = 360 - angle;}
    return angle;
};

//get unit vector
const unit_vector= (v) => {
    let width = get_width(v);
    return [v[0]/width, v[1]/width];
};

However, I get something similar to this as the following output
Single frame of the animation
Some boarders are thicker than others, and I'm not sure what the issue is

This is likely a rounding problem.  You're drawing each segment twice, since each segment belongs to two triangle.  If the rounding is slightly different, or if one is drawn top down and one bottom up, the results can differ.
